# Should NSArray and NSMutableArray be always used instead of normal C arrays?

Tags: c#, objective-c

I have a piece of code in C# and I am rewriting it in Objective C.
The code uses arrays a lot like double[]and also array of Point structure.
so shall i simply used C style array to store Objective C double and CGPoint for my task OR is it a good practice to use NSArrays or NSMutableArrays every time along with NSValue or NSNumber to store non-objects in them.

I could well use a plain array, but again this array is generated at runtime depending upon the size, so shall I use malloc and free to accomplish the same ?

NOTE: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/BezierSpline.aspx

This the C# code, I am trying to implement in Objective C, if anyone has a converted code, please help me out.
I tried but, doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: I would use the NS Classes, because you can do more operations on them as you can on normal arrays. What that is you can see in the class reference (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are converting from C#, in that language you can have both arrays of *unboxed* primitive types and structures, e.g. `double`, and arrays of *boxed* types, e.g. equivalent to `NSNumber` objects containing `double`s in Obj-C.

C# arrays of unboxed `double`s (same hold for other primitive types and structures) are someway between Obj-C  `double[]` and an `NSArray` of `NSNumber`s - in C# elements are unboxed (as in `double[]`) while the array itself is a managed object (as in `NSArray`).

C# boxed arrays are equivalent to `NSArray`s of `NSObject`s.

How do you choose?

- If the C# code has fixed-sized arrays of unboxed types use (Obj-)C arrays.
- If the C# code as varying-size arrays of boxed types use Obj-C `NSArray`s.
- If you are happy with C++ for variable-sized arrays of unboxed types consider `vector`.
- And for everything else balance the cost of boxing each element (10,000 `NSNumber`s have a high overhead compared to the same number of `double`s) vs. managing the memory for the array (`malloc`/`free` vs. `alloc`/`release` vs. ARC/GC). In general, but not as an absolute rule, arrays of unboxed types are best as C arrays while arrays of boxed types are best as `NSArray`s.

Comment: Hey, Please checkout the change in the question again and the link as well and tell me if this can directly be converted or not.

Answer (score 1):

While its usually better to use NS objects, when you have collections of 'non-objects' it's a trade-off between managing the memory yourself using malloc/free, or coercing non-object data into a storable object. Remember NSArray and so forth will only store NSObjects. For double you can use NSNumber as a container. For CGPoint and other structs, you can either create a new object type or coerce into an NSData object somehow.

Comment: You could also use Obective C++ and use std::vector so that does the memory manageent

Comment: To "box" (wrap a scalar in an object) CGPoint and other arbitrary C scalars (and POD C++ objects), the class to use is NSValue.